# How to get q method's dependency diagram?

Tags: .net

I am trying to find a tool that shows a dependency tree for method calls from an assembly. If the method call chain goes across assemblies, this would also be shown
I have looked at dependency walker and Reflector for .Net, these tools show assembly dependencies but I want drill down one more level to get the assembly method call dependencies

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com).